# How do I run my packaged binary in my Android app?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have an Android app that needs to run a custom binary app I wrote. I already built the binary using ndk and packaged it in the apk under res/raw

I did something like this to first run the su process.

```
Process process;
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
```

What do I do after this to run the binary from resources? There was another question here that suggested the use of AssetManager but I don't understand how to do it exactly. I checked out some opensource Apps (android-wifi-tether, etc.) that have binaries packaged with them and I don't see AssetManager anywhere in their source and don't understand how exactly they're doing it.

Comment: You cannot run a binary from the resources.  You would have to copy it out into a location in the file system where executables are permitted.  Also note that 'su' will only work on _some_ rooted phones.

Comment: Okay, so this needs to be done when the app is first run.. I'll give it a try

Comment: It works but the file is not executable. Is there a java way to make it executable, or do I just do Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 770 /path/to/binary"); ?

Comment: Normally it would be preferable to either find a java wrapper for the chmod/fchmod functions or call one those from ndk jni code rather than launch a separate process; however, your project already depends on the unofficial ability to exec a new process, so the argument against doing it that way is weaker.  Though you do a add a dependency on the system having a workable chmod executable in the path.

Comment: BEWARE! 'libs' folder does not exist in android6 galaxy s5, so this code WILL cause an exception. Instead libraries will be copied to 'lib' directory under application directory.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nasty hacky way to trick Android into doing this for you (which I do, successfully).

When the application is installed, Android will copy the appropriate libraries for your architecture out of `libs/$ARCH/libfoo.so` into `/data/data/$PACKAGE/libs` for you. The tricky bit is that it will *only* copy files of the form `lib$SOMETHING.so`. It'll even preserve the execute permissions.

So, if you rename your `su` executable to `libsu.so`, Android will do all the work for you. You can then find it using the paths available from Activity.

However, beware! Android is *not designed* to run standalone apps and Zygote really doesn't get on well with being forked. I've found that `Runtime.exec()` has race conditions and can crash. The only reliable technique I've found is to use JNI to implement a little library that does a fork and exec without touching any other data between the fork and the exec. I did have a question here about this with all the details, but I can't find it.

I don't have access to any of the code right now, but if you want I can find some of it for you on Monday.

Comment: src/main/libs is not worked for me, src/main/jniLibs is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to David Given's response, which is great, this is what I use at the end of Android.mk to rename the binary automatically. May be of some use to others trying the same thing:

```
...
LOCAL_MODULE := yourbinarynamehere

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

all: $(LOCAL_MODULE)
    $(shell (mv libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/$< libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib$<.so))
```

Mind the TAB before $(shell... spaces won't work as per standard GNU Make.

Comment: Thank you MartinMarco! And here for Windows-users: `all: $(LOCAL_MODULE)
 cmd /c move libs\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\$< libs\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\lib$<.so`

Answer (score 0):

There some directory already set as a folder named 'jniLibs' by jniLibs.srcDirs in build.gradle file

```
src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a
src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
src/main/jniLibs/x86
src/main/jniLibs/x86_64
```

You can change the path by setting in you app build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```