# Android Studio with c++ compiled binary

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, binaryfiles

i am new to Android Studio, and i have a c++ compiled binary `beat_tracker_Single.out` which i want to run in my Android Studio.

The c++ executable should run like this: Taking in an audio wave file (1st argument) and do some processing, and writes its output to a text file (2nd argument).

```sh
beat_tracker_Single.out "test.wav" "test.txt"
```

I generated an Android Studio simple script to play audio from this 5 minute tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lZl_idL8bY):
What it does is to play an audio from a specified wave file.

My next step is to have a button to run the `beat_tracker_Single.out` on it, how do i do that ?
I've seen several pages talking about making CMake and generating JNI files, im not sure if those are really required at the moment.

> Edit 1 : As per Botje's comment, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839767/how-do-i-run-my-packaged-binary-in-my-android-app) mentioned to do it this way:
> [image: MainActivity.java]

1. I renamed `beat_tracker_Single.out` to `beat_tracker_Single.so` and stored it together with the wave file in the `res/raw` folder
2. How do i write the process to run this script on the file path?
3. When I attempted to build the project, this is the current pop-up asking me how to deal with the `*.so` binary file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run my packaged binary in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839767/how-do-i-run-my-packaged-binary-in-my-android-app)

Comment: @Botje thanks for your reply! It sounds like something i should follow. But im not sure where where to start. After i put the `RunFunction.out` in the `res/raw` folder, whats next ?

Comment: @Botje i have included in `Edit 1` my current attempt using the provided link

Comment: The answer I linked talked about putting binaries in the libs directory, after which you can use the regular Runtime.exec call to run them from your application's data directory. Presumably (did not test this) the files in res/raw are not automatically executable.

Comment: @Botje How to i call them to run it in `Java` ? Usually on the linux command line, (`bash`) i run it this way `beat_tracker_Single.out test.wav test.txt`

Comment: Runtime.exec is the right approach (at least to see if it works); you just need to locate the proper path to your file first.

Comment: @Botje What im asking is, how should i use Runtime.exec ?
As per the picture above, i dont think i should write it this way : `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("libbeat_tracker_Single.so test.wav test.txt");`

Comment: Assuming you get the path to the file correct, that code should be fine.

Comment: @Botje What about for part 3, when i build, they are asking me what to do with the `*.so` file. which should i choose ?

Comment: You're not supposed to put it in res/raw, move it to the **libs** directory as the linked answer stated. Ignore the file association prompt, your IDE is trying to open it to point to line 1.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, now that i moved them to `libs` folder. What should the relative file path be ? `./libs/beat_tracker_Single.so` or simply just `beat_tracker_Single.so` ?